# How to remove item from nested array in partial view in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have recursive partial in angular for showing comments threads. And I have controls for edit and delete. Deleting working on server but i can't update client.
My main page:

```
 <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="ch in img.comments"  ng-include="'views/nestedComment.html'">

  </div>
```

My partial look like:

```
<div class="list-group-item-info">
<h4>{{ch.app_user.email}}:</h4>
{{ch.body}}
<div class="controls" ng-if="ch.app_user_id==user.getUser().id">
<a href="#" ng-click="edit(ch)"><%=t :edit %></a>
<a href="#" ng-click="deletenested(ch)"><%=t :destroy %></a>
<a href="#" ng-click="answer(ch)"><%=t :answer %></a>
<a href="#" ng-click="nested = ! nested"><%=t :shownested %></a>
<div class="list-group-item-danger" ng-repeat="ch in ch.children" ng-show="nested" ng-include="'views/nestedComment.html'">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I use this function to delete

```
 $scope.deletenested=function(parent,item){
    $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
        parent.children.splice(parent.children.indexOf(item),1);
    })
    $http.delete('/comments/'+item.id)
        .success(function(){
            alert('OK')
            parent.children.splice(parent.children.indexOf(item),1)
        })
        .error(function(response,status){
            if (status=='401'){
                alert('You have to autorize')
                $window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/app_users/sign_in';
            }
        })
}
```

This worked for me when i didn't use partials. But now i can't access to parent array.

Comment: You're calling the function with 1 parameter: `deletenested(ch)` but on your  function expression you are expecting 2 parameters? `$scope.deletenested=function(parent,item)`

Comment: You should move that http calls into a service and manage your data models outside your controllers. That way they'll be available everywhere and remove this problem.